# Getting to the latest version of java api documentation

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

When I want to consult the java API I usually go to a search engine and type e.g. "Java String" which gives me the link to the official documentation. The problem is that I never get the latest version(8) but instead mostly get the version 7, e.g.:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

What is the best way to always get directed to the latest version?

Alternatively, what is your preferred way to search for API documentation?

Comment: Replace the 7 with an 8 and then bookmark it.

Comment: Hint: you might want to have a bookmark to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/ ... when you go there, you are immediately greeted with the current/latest java version number. Just find your way from there.

Comment: "What is your preferred way to search for API documentation?" - in most cases I just read the JavaDoc on the version I'm currently using. That combined with an IDE that can provide a quick outline (fields, methods etc.) results in almost the same as the documentation you get on the web.

Comment: For me, the most efficient way to use Java API docs is to use built-in IDE function to check it. For example in IntelliJ IDEA you can just put the cursor on the class and hit Ctr+Q. This shortcut opens popup-like view with docs. This will always give you documentation for Java version used in the project.

Comment: @Kamil But it won't give you detailed descriptions, and sometimes I want to just dive into the doc and check the different methods available.

Comment: I have often had younger co-workers who insist on getting to Java’s javadoc this way.  I’ll tell you what I tell them:  Don't do that.  Download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ instead, and refer to your local copy.  It won’t change between minor releases, so you only have to download a new version every three years or so.

Comment: @VGR how do you search it? Or do you just browse it? I find it is fastest to just type "Java <class name>" into the search engine, it always brings me straight to the docs.

Comment: At the top of every single class’s javadoc is a blue navigation bar, whose links include “INDEX”.  You can search that page.  If you’re searching for a class, you can use the “All Classes” link in the upper-left frame to bring up a list of all classes in the frame below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I figured out:

Go to your search engine, type "Java 8". Bookmark this and add it to the bookmarks toolbar.

Now I just need to click this bookmark if I want to look up something.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of approaches for *ad hoc* searches:

- Replacing the `7` with an `8` in the URL will get you to the Java 8 version.
- Rather than searching `Java string` search for `Java 8 string`

Internally, we maintain our own Java API site generated by [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) configured to provide more detailed information such as collaborative diagrams, call and caller graphs, etc.

Comment: @roland Typing an ' 8 ' is superfluous? I prefer to call it narrowing the search scope.

Comment: What I meant, I don't want to type it *every* time I search the docs. That is exactly the point of my question.

Comment: @roland The primary topic of your question is how to ensure getting to the right version of JavaDocs when following your usual search engine approach, not the effectiveness/efficiency of keystrokes in doing so. Furthermore, deleting comments that have been replied to is not a good practice. You have exhausted my attention. Thank you for using SO.